# pandas.merge is adding extra rows

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I've got a number of CSV files with 3 fields:
file 1:

```
name desc count
AAA aaa 5
BBB bbb 15 ...
```

file 2:

```
name desc count
ZZZ zzz 5
BBB bbb 25 ...
```

The number of rows (and unique keys) is around 7000 for each of the three first files. The name and desc are my keys and some of these are shared between the different files as in the examples above.
I've got a loop to merge the files and it works well for the three firsts. Here is my call:

```
testfile = pandas.merge(testfile, file1 to fileN, on= ['name', 'desc'], how = 'outer')
```

The results of the loop looks like this (I only presented the two first columns):

```
name desc count_x count_y ...
AAA aaa 5  NaN ..   
BBB bbb 15 25 ..
ZZZ zzz NaN 5 ..
```

After 3 merging the testfile.shape is 8782 x 5 as expected.
The fourth file is smaller than the others 3647 x 3 and the merging seems to work OK however the resulting file has a number of extralines at the end like this :

```
name  desc  count_x  count_y  count_x  index_y  count_y...
8943   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   3419   1...
```

and the testfile.shape is 8973 x 7 while it should be 8782 x 6.
I tried the solution for a similar issue in [Pandas Merge (pd.merge) How to set the index and join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341805/pandas-merge-pd-merge-how-to-set-the-index-and-join) to no avail.

I would appreciate if somebody tell me what is wrong with my approach and how to sort this out. I can share the files if necessary.

Comment: Well when you merge on keys if any of the other row values don;t match then this creates a clash and this appends new columns with suffixes `_x` and `_y`, you need to decide what to do in this case

Comment: Thanks but why is it that it can cope with few extra rows as in the first example of merged files and not when I merged a file with lot of extra rows? The merged function in R can accommodate it and I was expecting the pandas package to do so too.

Comment: Well you'll have to post data and code that demonstrates this, there may be a number of reasons

Comment: Thanks. I'm happy to share the file and code.Due to the size of the files I posted them here: https://www.ebi.ac.uk/~hudenise/MERGING_ISSUES/ with a README file to explain what the files are. @EdChum

Comment: Sorry its a little unclear what you are merging exactly, is it just the 4 ipr files? they have no headers so what are the column names?

Comment: I would like to merge the ipr files using the first and second columns (renamed "IPR" and "description" by the script). The third entry in these files is the abundance in a particular sample. I would like to obtain something like IPR_abundance3.tsv with abundances from the fourth file added. Ultimately, I should be able to give a list with any number of files and merged them together, inserting NaN if the IPR/description is absent from a number  of the files.

Comment: Sorry I think you have to do more debugging here step by step to narrow down what you're doing wrong, as I don't have time to decrypt your code, as it stands the reason you will get these additional columns is because your keys you are merging on contain no matches on both sides, you'll have to debug that at each stage to see where it's going wrong. As it stands there is no way anyone could tell you what is wrong based on your submitted information

Comment: Basically I've got a loop loading the files in the order of the list and merging them sequentially using the command I provided:

Comment: Sorry did not finish my comment: I've got a loop loading files and merging them sequentially using the command I provided: pandas.merge(mergfile, file1 to fileN, on= ['IPR', 'desc'], how = 'outer'). As I said it works for the three first merging but not when the fourth is added. This can be tested without using my script using the files I provided by uploading the IPR_abundance3.tsv and merging it with the ERR770961_MERGED_FASTQ_summary.ipr. Let me know what I could provide in addition. This issue can be reproduced using smaller files if the number of keys ("IPR/Desc") differ significantly.